# MYSQL Selecting reciprocating data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `Follow`, with three fields:

- Id (autoincrement int),
- UserId (int),
- Following (int)

If I have data like this:

```
ID    UserId    Following   
--------------------------
1       2          3
2       3          2
3       2          5
4       2          6
5       3          5
```

How would I find user 2's friends (ie: user 2 is following them, and they follow user 2)

I guess, in other words, if user 'a' follows user 'b', and user 'b' follows user 'a', how do I select user A ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.UserId, a.Following
  FROM Follow a INNER JOIN Follow b
    ON a.UserId = b.Following
   AND b.UserId = a.Following
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select f1.UserId
from Follow f1
join Follow f2 on f2.Following = f1.UserId and f2.UserId = f1.Following
```